# Parallel processing of tasks in python using multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Here is my code for executing tasks in parallel. The program executes all the shell commands to resize all the icons using the magick program.

```py
import glob
from subprocess import run
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool, cpu_count
import time
import os

class ParallelProcess:
    def __init__(self, files):
        """Constructor
        
        Args:
            files (List[str]): A list of icon files. 
        """
        self.files = files

    def parallel_resize(self, file):
        """Task function for multiprocessing Pool.
        
        Args:
            file (TYPE): Icon file path
        """
        
        print("Resizing : {}".format(file))
        cmnd = "magick {} -resize 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100 ./out/{}".format(file, os.path.basename(file))
        try:
            data = run(cmnd, capture_output=True, shell=True)
            errors = data.stderr.splitlines()
            if errors:
                for e in errors:
                    print(e.decode())
                exit()
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e.stderr)
            exit()

    def execute_parallel(self):
        '''Execute tasks in parallel.
        '''
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
          
        try:
            pool = Pool()  
            pool.map(self.parallel_resize, self.files, 4)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.stderr)

        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        print("Program finished in {} seconds.".format(end_time-start_time))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = ParallelProcess(glob.glob("./rabbits/*.ico"))
    t.execute_parallel()
```

The results are:

```py
Serial processing finished in 5.773 seconds.
Parallel processing finished in 2.01 seconds. chunk size = 1
Parallel processing finished in 2.181 seconds. chunk size = 4
Parallel processing finished in 2.2651441 seconds. chunk size = 8
```

On my Intel i9, 8 processors (4 logical) laptop, the results of using different chunk sizes are shown. I am not able to figure out how to choose the correct chunk size. I will be using the above code to process thousands of images.

How do I handle interrupts? I have purposely copied a corrupt icon file in the directory. When magick processes that file, errors are produced. In that case, the processing should immediately stop, but I'm not able to figure it out correctly, although I'm still trying.

Practically, I can think of two ways to stop:

1. As soon as an error is produced, finish the files in the queue and stop.
2. Immediately stop, even drop the tasks in the queue.

thus How do you handle an error interruption correctly?

Prashant

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get CalledProcessError with this code because you don't include `check=True` in `run()`. Do you want all non-zero exit codes to raise an error?

Comment: using a process pool to execute another process is never going to lead to amazing performance.  you're likely better of using something else (e.g. a `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`) as the time spent in Python should be minimal given the code you've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; Use `imap_unordered`, set `chunksize=1` and move the worker out of the class definition.

TLRDR; Use threads instead.

There is a cost to passing data between the parent process and its workers. If the operation performed is short, this cost can dominate, making multiprocessing slower than doing the work serially. By default, the pool will send / receive in chunks to minimize this overhead.

But there are downsides. If some data processes faster than others, you have to wait for the chunk that just happened to have the most expensive calculations to complete, even if all of the other workers are done and could have been used for the expensive stuff. And other problems like a worker raising an exception are not seen until chunk processing completes.

Pool.map and Pool.imap both maintain the order of operations, so they have to accumulate results, and this also decreases responsiveness when errors are raised. Since you don't care about maintaining order, use `imap_unordered` instead.

Be careful about serializing more stuff than you need to. Your worker self.parallel_resize means that the whole ParallelProcess object needs to be serialized for the workers. But that is fragile and unnecessary. Make your worker a function instead.

Finally, why go MP? All you are doing is executing a program which is a separate process anyway. Just use a thread pool and save the cost of using processes.

```
import glob
from subprocess import run
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time
import os

def parallel_resize(file):
    """Task function for Pool.
    
    Args:
        file (TYPE): Icon file path
    """
    
    print("Resizing : {}".format(file))
    cmnd = "magick {} -resize 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100 ./out/{}".format(file, os.path.basename(file))
    # let errors propegate to caller
    data = run(cmnd, capture_output=True, shell=True, check=True)
    if data.stderr:
        # treat any stderr traffic as error
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(data.returncode, data.args, 
            data.stdout, data.stderr)


class ParallelProcess:
    def __init__(self, files):
        """Constructor
        
        Args:
            files (List[str]): A list of icon files. 
        """
        self.files = files

    def execute_parallel(self):
        '''Execute tasks in parallel.
        '''
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        
        try:
            with ThreadPool() as pool: 
                list(pool.imap_unordered(parallel_resize, self.files, chunksize=1))
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(e.stderr.decode())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        print("Program finished in {} seconds.".format(end_time-start_time))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = ParallelProcess(glob.glob("./rabbits/*.ico"))
    t.execute_parallel()
```

This code should very beat your `chunksize=1` test case and should be responsive to errors to the extent that other threads will finish their current call to `magick` but not progress further.

Comment: Execution time has reduced to 1.65 seconds. code doesn't stop on error but hangs.

Comment: That's better than I expected, except the hanging part. I'll take another look.

Comment: I did my testing with multiprocessing then failed to change `exit()` to something else in the thread version. `exit()` raises `SystemExit` but that is handled specially in threads, causing the hang problem. Instead, I let CalledProcessError to propagate back to the caller to be handled.

Comment: It's working and giving the lowest timings between 1.65 - 1.80 seconds including error handling.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Chunksize will split a list into chunks of approximatley that size. So if you want to use all cores you should use length / nproc, where length is the size of the items, and nproc is the number of threads you have (can be found with `nproc` on linux)

As for the stop on error you can use a shared memory flag, where as soon as it is set, all the others will stop asap. Here's an example of how to do this

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

def worker(inp):
    flag = inp[0].buf
    data = inp[1]
    if flag[0]:
        return
    if data == False:
        flag[0] = True
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 50
    flag = SharedMemory(create = True, size = 1)
    data = [True] * 50
    data[30] = False

    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(worker, zip([flag] * n, data))

    print(flag.buf[0])

    flag.close()
    flag.unlink()
```

<s>I haven't tested this yet. I'll edit once I have</s>
Tested on Python 3.11.3

Comment: Add if __name__ == '__main__':  before n =50 or else code won't work

Comment: It does work for me, but I'll add it anyway

Comment: `__name__ == "__main__"` is needed on spawning systems like Windows but not forking systems like linux. That's why it fails for some and not others.